# oauth2ResourceServer for specific uri

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, jwt

Hi I am looking to set up oauth2ResourceServer for ping sso using oauth2 for a specific client which uses this authentication for our rest service. The other clients don't use this at the moment and to get them upgraded would take some time. How do I set this up for just specific URI.

Note: all clients hit the rest service with different uri like ../client1/resource
../client2/resource

Can I filter if using

```
http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

and provide a customer Authentication provider like
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider? If so, how to setup the oauth2 server here?

This is what I intent to do (not figured out how to do it with a specific uri)

```
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
            oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter()))
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                    .accessDeniedHandler(unauthorizedHandler)
            );
```

Comment: Just use two security filter chains, one with OAuth2 and one without it.

Comment: Looking at using a Provider as we have others at the moment instead of using filter chains. Looking to setup a provider with jwks

Comment: How did you end up solving this?